# unity не находит анимацию

Tags: unity3d

Создал анимацию для кнопки, в скрипте прописал чтобы анимация проигрывалась пи нажатии, но пишет что анимация не найдена.

Вот окно объекта:

[image: окно объекта с скриптом нажатия, анимацией и скриптом]

Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class OnPlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public void SceneChanger() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
    public void OnClickAnimator() {
        Animation anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
        anim.Play();
    }
}
```

пробовал и `anim.Play("PlayClickAnimation")` тоже не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это, Скопируй и вставь это в твой OnPlay
Я изменил твой код.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class OnPlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    Private Animation anim;
    public void Start() {
        anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    }
    public void SceneChanger() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
    public void OnClickAnimator() {
        anim.Play();
    }
}
```